# Including fields from related object in a junction object view?

Tags: junction-object

Is it possible to include fields from related objects in a junction object?

Let's say I am building an order system. I have an Order object, Product object, and an OrderProducts object. I want to show the OrderProducts list on a the Order details page, but I want to include specific attributes from the Product object in that list. Assuming OrderProducts only has Order and Product fields, how do I also show, say UPC Code, and Supplier fields long side those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need to use Cross Object Lookup Formulas:
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_cross_object.htm&language=en_US

With these, you can add fields to the junction object that reference fields on the parent objects as formulas